# no such column: app_entry.author_id

Tags: django-models

i am deleting my migration file again and again but still i am facing the same error..

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.FileField()
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-date']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Deleting the migration file will not help. In fact if you have an existing database, now it will be worse, since now Django does no longer know what the *current* state of the database will be.

Comment: You need to `makemigration`, and then effectively `migrate` the database.

Comment: i did makemigrations and migrate --fake but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to this step this work most of the times:

1. Delete migrations from the app you are having trouble.
    Example: let's consider it as ***'myapp'***
2. Check for the apps your model is related(means having a foreign key constrain).
     Example: let's consider it as ***'django.contrib.auth'***
3. Run migrations for these apps (which we have found in step 2) individually. Like this

```
python manage.py makemigrations django.contrib.auth
```

4. Now run cmd

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

It should resolve your problem. Correct me of doesn't